# Complex slug in Bolt.cm

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a content type with a relation with another content type.
I want the later to contain the related element in the slug.

I have: universities (Content type)
Classes (Content type)

I want the slug for classes to be: classes/universityX/className
I'm trying to setup my YML file with something like:

```
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: [university,name]
```

But it raises an error.
Is there any way to accomplish this? The kitchensink example does the same, but using a regular field in the content type.

Thanks!

The error is:

```
  In the contenttype for 'cursos', the field 'slug' has 'uses: universidades', but the field 'universidades' does not exist. Please edit contenttypes.yml, and correct this.
```

Comment: Please don't post the error it raises, it's absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: yes errors are completely useless to find the solution..

Comment: Sorry, i didn't though of that, it's basically saying that the field doesn't exist (Totally right, since it's a relation)